# Multiple forms on single page rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am building a web-application in Rails 3.2 where I have a person model which has multiple addresses associated with it. Now I am trying to add new addresses through the edit window of the person.

To create the layout of the page I use bootstrap.

I have created a simple edit view were I am able to edit all the details of a person and which has a simple table that shows the addresses associated with it. This view is created with a simple_form_for and doesn't have the remote tag set to true.

Below the table there is a button that loads remotely the view for a new address, this is accomplished with the following piece of code:

```
=link_to 'Add new address', new_address_path(:addressable_id => @person.id, :addressable_type => @person.class.name), :data => {:toggle => "modal", :target => "#newAddressWindow"}, :remote => true, :class => 'btn'

.modal#newAddressWindow{:style => "display: none;"}
```

This loads a new form in a modal dialog from bootstrap through the following code:

addresses_controller:

```
def new
    @address = Address.new

    @address.addressable_type = params[:addressable_type]
    @address.addressable_id = params[:addressable_id]

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @address }
      format.js
    end
end
```

addresses/new.js.erb

```
if ($("#newAddressWindow").is(':empty')) {
    $("#newAddressWindow").append(
        "<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'form') %>"
    );
}
```

addresses/_form.html.haml

```
= simple_form_for(@address, :remote => true) do |f|
  .modal#myModal
    .modal-header
      %button.close{:href => "#", :data => {:dismiss => "modal"}}x
      %h3 Adres
    .modal-body
      = f.input :postal_code
      = f.input :number
      = f.input :city
      = f.input :addressable_id, :as => :hidden
      = f.input :addressable_type, :as => :hidden
    .modal-footer
      %a.btn{:href => "#", :data => {:dismiss => "modal"}} Close
      = f.button :submit, :class => "btn-primary"
```

Now what I want is to submit the address and show the newly submitted address in the table of the person. But when I press the submit button the create action of addresses is called as a normal html call, as I can see from my server log, where I expected it to be an ajax call to the server because of the remote in the form. After the submit the server also redirects me the create page of addresses.

This is what I see in the server log:

> Started POST "/addresses" for 84.107.25.142 at 2012-05-09 13:10:14 +0200
>   Processing by AddressesController#create as HTML
>
> Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"WBBKxMftlsvHF5B6zgJw/wtBdF4IibquJQ6HrM6b0cQ=", "address"=>{"postal_code"=>"5", "number"=>"6", "city"=>"7", "addressable_id"=>"2", "addressable_type"=>"Person"}, "commit"=>"Create Address"}

And this is the create action of the addresses controller

```
def create
  @address = Address.new(params[:address])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @address }
    format.js
  end
end
```